# Fractal generator for android Bitmap / Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to create a Fractal generator for Android.

The only unclear thing I have in my list is: which class should I use, in order to display the result on the screen? I need to have something like a bitmap, to be able to get the current width / height and to be able to set some pixels (RGB), without having every pixel to be a different object.

I saw I can use the Bitmap class, but I am not sure if this is the right way.

As an extra, I also want to be able to set the generated screen to the background and save the result to a file.

Which class I should use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `canvas.drawPoint()`:

`To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing).`

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPoint(float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can do just a pixel? e.g. what primitive and what Paint i need to use?

Comment: Yes, drawPoint: `Helper for drawPoints() for drawing a single point.`

Answer (score 0):

I used this for a fractal tree:

```
private fun drawTree(canvas: Canvas, x1: Float, y1: Float, angle: Double, depth: Int) {
    if (depth == 0) return
    val x2 = x1 + (cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0).toInt()
    val y2 = y1 + (sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0).toInt()
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, panoramictextpaint)
    drawTree(canvas, x2, y2, angle - 20, depth - 1)
    drawTree(canvas, x2, y2, angle + 20, depth - 1)
}
```